# .htaccess rewrite two get variables

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to use two get variables in rewrite.

Example of what I am trying to do

```
htt://xx x.com/admin/agents/create
```

My code is not working  :

```
RewriteRule ^admin/(dashboard|settings|logout|agents)/(.*)?$ admin/index.php?a=$1&b=$1 [L]
```

*Note : Only in agents have second variable (&b=).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^admin/(dashboard|settings|logout|agents)/(.*)?$ admin/index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L]
```

`$1` is the backreference to `(dashboard|settings|logout|agents)`, whereas `$2` is the backreference to `(.*)`. If the request URL is `http://www.example.com/admin/agents/create`, it is internal rewritten to `/admin/index.php?a=agents&b=create`